# Why is there a sewer gas smell coming from my door jamb?

Tags: bathroom, basement

I am at the tail end of tiling my basement floor and undercut the existing trim on the bathroom door.  I started noticing a sewage smell and pinpointed it as being strongest at this point.  This is about 1' from the toilet, and the concrete seemed to stop here, so I exposed a small air pocket by cutting into the trim.

What could be the problem here and how can I address it?  Would I call a plumber to remove the toilet and have a look?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely need to pull the toilet. It may as simple as a bad wax seal, or rotted closet flange. But since it looks like a raised floor, there could be more serious issues like a broken or rotted drain pipe. Unless you feel comfy pulling the toilet, call a plumber immediately and STOP using the toilet and sinks in that bathroom.